# Wrong rendering of code blocks by readthedocs + mkdocs

Tags: css, markdown, documentation, read-the-docs, mkdocs

I am having an issue with rendering code blocks in a documentation project using Mkdocs with readthedocs theme. Code blocks seem to not parse correctly new lines, so all code in a code block is rendered as a single line.

The repo can be used to reproduce the example,  https://github.com/segrelab/comets-manual. The rendering can be seen in https://segrelab.github.io/comets-manual/.

The only hint I have found on google is [this](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/issues/1692) but it doesn't seem to be providing any solution, beyond identifying that the problem is related to css (indeed, I ave tried other themes and the code blocks render correctly).

Does anybody have an idea of how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please make sure that your tool is up to date (I can't reproduce the wrong rendering of the code blocks):

```
pip install --upgrade mkdocs
```

If the problem persists, you can make a workaround with `extra.css` (by the way, `extra.css` and `extra.js` must locate at `docs/css/extra.css` and `docs/js/extra.js`; see [this](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/issues/1452#issuecomment-378087753)).
By guessing from the current-rendered page, the following should work:

```css
/* docs/css/extra.css */

code, .rst-content tt, .rst-content code {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

which is somehow set to `white-space: nowrap;` in the rendered page.